# How to find out if there is a break point in a very big class file(vb/c# .net)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, breakpoints, shortcut

I am asking this if there is a shortcut for finding this out with out scrolling a file all the way??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-Using the Breakpoints Window
-From the Debug menu, choose Windows and click Breakpoints.
-for more info, check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/02ckd1z7(v=vs.71).aspx